# Can we change the acceptance of answer if more perfect answer gets appeared later?

Tags: discussion

I has asked question and one user provided the answer, The solution was perfect, but the approach was different. Since it solved my issue, I accepted it as a answer. Few days later, some other user answered and this answer is perfect in terms of approach as well as solving the issue.

Now, I have already awarded the acceptance of answer, and now this perfect answer appeared. So, as a **professional point of view**, I should not change that selection of answer, but again I am thinking there is other answer is there which is providing perfect solution.

Now, If I think **Technical point of view**, so it raises some concern in my mind that, if in future somebody reads that question, he will be more going to use the answer which I have accepted as this might be general tendency, so that answer which is perfect will always be in shadow. So, there is a chances that future user will not get the perfect answer which is already available.

So, what should I need to do in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accepting an answer is to show what helped you, the asker of the question, the most.

If another answer comes along that helped you more than one that you already accepted, then feel free to mark the newer one as accepted instead.

The point is It's completely your choice. Don't worry about professionalism, people losing points, etc, the idea is that the person who asks the question gets to indicate what helped them the most, and it's not intended to be set in stone once you've accepted one.